# UncaughtReference Error: function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick after using webpack

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, webpack

i am generating bundle file from 2 typescript file after bundling kept getting the error UncaughtReference Error: function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick
i dont know what it means can anyone help me out.

[tscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMpfb.png)

[tscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldsxr.png)

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A64w.png)

that's my Webpack generated bundled file

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./index231.ts");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./index231.ts":
/*!*********************!*\
  !*** ./index231.ts ***!
  \*********************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

throw new Error("Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:8)\nYou may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders\n| \n| export class  v {\n>     con : a;\n|     constructor()\n|     {");

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

index231.ts file

```
import   a  from "./index";


export class  v {
    con : a;
    constructor()
    {
        // super();
      this.con =  new a();
      this.con.hd();
    }
    static run()
    {
        console.log("donne")
    }
}
```

index.ts

```
export default class a 
{
    hd()
    {

        console.log("dkhg");
    }

}
```

html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Document</title>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value = "click[enter image description here][4]" onclick="new v()" id="jg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide minimal working example.

Comment: If you don't add relevant code to your question, it is going to be closed very quickly.

Comment: what else you need

Answer (score 0):

there may be 2 ways 
a more suitable way I think is making your variable global that you are using.

i.e window.[alias name] = variable name